# Reading in python strings previously written to files

Tags: python

I have a legacy database-as-file-system, whereby a series of files were written containing Python strings. Since I'm still learning python, I'm looking for the most pythonic way to handle this. While I could just parse the files as text, it's not certain that all the data strictly conforms to a standard. It's a file system with over 20,000 files.

The system structure is as follows:

```
Object1\
  Object1.py
Object2\
  Object2.py
...
```

Within each ObjectN.py, is the following

```
Attribute1 = '''
This is the data behind attribute 1
which may span 1 or more than 1 line or be empty
'''

Attribute2 = '''
...
```

You get the picture.

Is there a Python way to simply "execute" the python files themselves and have the data assigned in Attribute1's store be retrievable directly? Or does something custom need to be designed?

Thanks!

Comment: Other than with `import`?

Comment: I've tried that but they are not valid modules. I can go into more detail if you need to but I get Tracebacks when trying that.

Comment: Well, I can use import if I rename the files... for the purposes of moving forward, I'll try that. For specificity, my files are actually named Object1.type.py, and importing neither "Object1" nor "Object1.type" is allowed.